# What value does the compiler assign to an uninitialised member of a const struct in C?

Tags: c, constants

Say I have a `struct` `typedef` that is:

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t memberOne;
    int32_t memberTwo;
} myStruct_t;
```

I instantiate a `const` of that type as follows:

`const myStruct_t myConst = {.memberTwo = 32};`

What does C say the compiler should set `memberOne` to be?  I've tried it, of course, and I happen to get 0 on the compilers I've tried, what I'm after here is does the C standard **require** uninitialised members of a `const` `struct` to be initialised to something or other by the compiler, i.e. would the code above be considered portable?  Clause 6.7.9 of C99 says:

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

...but what about `const`s?  Are they considered to be of `static` storage type, just without the `static` keyword?

Comment: It will the same as if you didn't qualify with `const `.

Comment: The `const` is not what you should focus on. You might look at this: *21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.*

Comment: @Gerhardh aaah, that's what I was after!  I should have read on.

Comment: C actually allows `const myStruct_t myConst;` with automatic storage duration... which will hold indeterminate values. So `const` doesn't matter at all, only storage duration of the struct object as well as the initializer list matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does the C standard require uninitialised members of a const struct to be initialised to something

Yes, they are guaranteed to be set to zero/null pointers as long as you initialize at least one member explicitly. `const` plays no part in it.

You've already found the relevant part about how objects with static storage duration are initialized. Just keep reading the same chapter:

C17 6.7.9 §19

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a
> particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject;
> all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as
> objects that have static storage duration.

C17 6.7.9 §21

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an
> aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
> are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as
> objects that have static storage duration.